# Passing csv data set config file as parameter to JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to be able to pass a CSV file containing parameters for a JMeter test (CSV Data Set Config) to use instead of having the CSV Data Source hard coded as part of the JMeter test. Is this possible? I cannot seem to find this anywhere / in the list of command-line options for JMeter.

Reference for [JMeter Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible, but don't use JMeter Variables as a part of CSV Filename as they are being initialized **after** CSV Data Set Config so you'll get "file not found" errors. Go for JMeter Properties instead.

1. In CSV Data Set Config instead of hard-coded filename use JMeter property reference via [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function like:

   - ${__P(csvfile,)}
   - ${__property(csvfile,,)}

     [image: CSV File Property Name]
2. Aforementioned `csvfile` property which pointing to the CSV file path can be defined in 2 ways:

   - in *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder) like:

     ```
     csvfile=/path/to/your/file.csv
     ```
   - via `-J` command-line argument like

     ```
     jmeter -Jcsvfile=/path/to/file.csv -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl
     ```

   Property value specified via command-line will override the one which is stored in the file. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information regarding JMeter properties and ways of working with them

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to manipulate the file you pass to the Jmeter via a variable, you need to create a user defined variable and then map that variable in CSV Dataset Config.
In the following example, I am passing a csv file that can be controlled at runtime via the parameter cids

Step 1: Define user defined variables. In my case, I am using three different csv files.

[image]

Step 2: call these variables as file names in each csv dataset config.

[image]

Now, you have a jmx, the inputs to which can be controlled by the user defined variables. This is pretty convenient when you schedule jobs via maven or similar ones.

Comment: This does not work for reasons specified above by Dimitri T

Comment: Maybe it is because a while had passed since the answer was published, but after trying out this solution, i can confirm that it does work without any issue, and is more comfortable than Dimitri T's solution, since you dont need to use the "user.params" file or pass an argument.